# Freetuxtv crashing

Tags: tv

I have been trying to run freetuxtv (the last version) in Ubuntu 15.04. The app loads available channels but crashesas soon as the window opens. The bug I get is SIGSEGV in gtk_tree_store_append(). So my question is whether anybody has been successful in making some earlier version working?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same issue on Ubuntu 16.04 with xfce-desktop.  I did some scouring on the net and found a ppa that worked great for me and got freetuxtv working.  Keep in mind it is the unstable freetuxtv Developer Team PPA found [here](https://launchpad.net/~freetuxtv/+archive/ubuntu/freetuxtv-dev)

you can install using the following

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:freetuxtv/freetuxtv-dev

sudo apt update

sudo apt install freetuxtv
```

This will install the latest version from the git repository on your system.
You don't need to type `apt-get` anymore in 16.04, you can just use `apt`

I hope this was helpful.